# ggplot2 shading envelope of time series

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting the results of 50 - 100 experiments.
Each experiment results in a time series. 
I can plot a spaghetti plot of all time series, but 
what I'd like to have is sort of a density map for the time series plume.
(something similar to the gray shading in the lower panel
in this figure: http://www.ipcc.ch/graphics/ar4-wg1/jpg/fig-6-14.jpg)

[image]

I can 'sort of' do this with 2d binning or binhex but the result could be prettier (see example below).

Here is a code that reproduces a plume plot for mock data (uses ggplot2 and reshape2).

```
# mock data: random walk plus a sinus curve.
# two envelopes for added contrast.
tt=10*sin(c(1:100)/(3*pi))
rr=apply(matrix(rnorm(5000),100,50),2,cumsum) +tt
rr2=apply(matrix(rnorm(5000),100,50),2,cumsum)/1.5 +tt

# stuff data into a dataframe and melt it.
df=data.frame(c(1:100),cbind(rr,rr2) )
names(df)=c("step",paste("ser",c(1:100),sep=""))
dfm=melt(df,id.vars = 1)

# ensemble average
ensemble_av=data.frame(step=df[,1],ensav=apply(df[,-1],1,mean))
ensemble_av$variable=as.factor("Mean")


ggplot(dfm,aes(step,value,group=variable))+
  stat_binhex(alpha=0.2) + geom_line(alpha=0.2) +
  geom_line(data=ensemble_av,aes(step,ensav,size=2))+
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

Does anyone know of a nice way do get a shaded envelope with gradients. I have also tried geom_ribbon but that did not give any indication of density changes along the plume. binhex does that, but not with aesthetically pleasing results.

Comment: I suspect you want to compute quantiles of your series at each time point, in your case in 10% quantiles from 0 to 100, then use `geom_ribbon` on those.

Answer (score 12):

Compute quantiles:

```
qs = data.frame(
   do.call(
       rbind,
       tapply(
         dfm$value, dfm$step, function(i){quantile(i)})),
   t=1:100)

head(qs)
         X0.      X25.      X50.     X75.     X100. t
1 -0.8514179 0.4197579 0.7681517 1.396382  2.883903 1
2 -0.6506662 1.2019163 1.6889073 2.480807  5.614209 2
3 -0.3182652 2.0480082 2.6206045 4.205954  6.485394 3
4 -0.1357976 2.8956990 4.2082762 5.138747  8.860838 4
5  0.8988975 3.5289219 5.0621513 6.075937 10.253379 5
6  2.0027973 4.5398120 5.9713921 7.015491 11.494183 6
```

Plot ribbons:

```
ggplot() + 
 geom_ribbon(data=qs, aes(x=t, ymin=X0., ymax=X100.),fill="gray30", alpha=0.2) +
 geom_ribbon(data=qs, aes(x=t, ymin=X25., ymax=X75.),fill="gray30", alpha=0.2)
```

[image: quantile intervals]

This is for two quantile intervals, (0-100) and (25-75). You'll need more args to `quantile` and more ribbon layers for more quantiles, and need to adjust the colours too.

Comment: Thanks, this is very nice and in the direction of what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the idea of Spacedman, I found a way to add more intervals in an automatic way: I first compute the quantiles for each `step`, group them by pairs of *symmetric* values and then use `geom_ribbon` in the right order...

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
condquant <- dfm %>% group_by(step) %>%
  do(quant = quantile(.$value, probs = seq(0,1,.05)), probs = seq(0,1,.05)) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  mutate(delta = 2*round(abs(.5-probs)*100)) %>% 
  group_by(step, delta) %>%
  summarize(quantmin = min(quant), quantmax= max(quant))

ggplot() +
  geom_ribbon(data = condquant, aes(x = step, ymin = quantmin, ymax = quantmax,
                                    group = reorder(delta, -delta), fill = as.numeric(delta)),
              alpha = .5) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "grey10", high = "grey95") + 
  geom_line(data = dfm, aes(x = step, y = value, group=variable), alpha=0.2) +
  geom_line(data=ensemble_av,aes(step,ensav),size=2)+
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

Comment: Thanks,
Due to the way my system is set up `dplyr` is erratic, so I recoded the definition of `condquant` using just older tools. But the result is much prettier than what I had arrived at earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Erwan and Spacedman.

Avoiding 'tidyr' ('dplyr' and 'magrittr') my version of Erwans answer becomes

```
probs=c(0:10)/10  # use fewer quantiles than Erwan
arr=t(apply(df[,-1],1,quantile,prob=probs))
dfq=data.frame(step=df[,1],arr)
names(dfq)=c("step",colnames(arr))
dfqm=melt(dfq,id.vars=c(1))
# add inter-quantile (per) range as delta 
 dfqm$delta=dfqm$variable
 levels(dfqm$delta)=abs(probs-rev(probs))*100


dfplot=ddply(dfqm,.(step,delta),summarize,
  quantmin=min(value),
  quantmax=max(value) )

ggplot() +
  geom_ribbon(data = dfplot, aes(x = step, ymin = quantmin, 
                               ymax =quantmax,group=rev(delta),
                               fill = as.numeric(delta)),
             alpha = .5) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "grey25", high = "grey75") +
  geom_line(data=ensemble_av,aes(step,ensav),size=2) + 
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image: Result of code]